# Increment a number field via a trigger INSERT in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm building a data versioning system, and I need to increment a version number each time a new row is added to the version table, but it increments once and then stops:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER trigger2 AFTER UPDATE ON something
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.updated_at <> OLD.updated_at THEN
            INSERT INTO versions_something (
                `id`,
                `some_id`,
                `version`,
                `title`,
                `description`,
                `created_at`,
                `updated_at`
            ) VALUES (
                null,
                NEW.id,
                1,
                NEW.title,
                NEW.description,
                NOW(),
                NOW()
            );
        END IF;
        UPDATE
            versions_something
        SET
            version = (SELECT MAX(version)) + 1
        WHERE versions_something.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

I've tried putting the UPDATE into a separate trigger (`AFTER INSERT ON versions_something ...`), but MySQL complains that it's clashing with the trigger before it.

I've tried the `UPDATE` on its own, using the last ID in the table and it works each time, so I have no idea what's happening.

Comment: Instead of voting the question down, and since I'm neither psychic or the knower of all things, might it not be a better idea to provide _actual_ feedback? An idea I'll leave here.

Comment: Have you considered an auto-increment column?  They auto-increment each time you add a new entry.  If you want to know the number of lines, use `SELECT COUNT()`.  If you need the highest value, use `SELECT MAX()`

Comment: With no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement. -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id Do you have and auto_increment field and if its id why attempt to set it to null

Comment: @Nic3500, an AUTO_INCREMENT attribute has to be used with a primary key, and I was getting errors in Larevel when I tried setting that up.

Comment: @P.Salmon, as I explained to Nic, I got errors in Laravel when I tried creating a field with an AUTO_INCREMENT attribute.

Comment: Hum, no mention of Laravel in your question or tags, it pays to be precise :-)